# How to copy css from Developers Tool if using Compass

Tags: html, css, compass

I just started using Compass for my style.
I used to edit my css in the developers tool then copy paste it in my css file but in compass, it is not applicable. In Compass, we edit on a sass file then compile it to css that is red by the html.
Is there any way to still used this even using the compass?

Comment: You can write CSS and decompile to SASS, then copy-paste to SASS file to later compile it to CSS

Comment: Generate a [source map file](http://thesassway.com/intermediate/using-source-maps-with-sass) for your Sass and you should be able to see Sass code in DevTools. But, on top of that, I'd suggest stopping this practice. Use some build tool like [Gulp](https://gulpjs.com/) or [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) and some live refresh browser plugin ([nodemon](https://nodemon.io/), [browser-sync](https://browsersync.io/)...) instead.